# First and third saturday disable fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I want to disable first and third saturday of the month and I'm using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)  library to show all events on my calendar. is it possible to to the same? please advice, answers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you want to hide or just disable all select action of first and third Saturday?

Answer (score -1):

Include [Date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/list) in your project. Now use the following code.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: checkBadDates
        });
      }
```

So here I’m just setting the date format and using the beforeShowDay event to call a function to check if any of the dates should be disabled:

```
var fisrtSaturday=Date.today().first().saturday();  
var thirdSaturday=Date.today().third().saturday();      
var $myBadDates = new Array(fisrtSaturday,thirdSaturday);
function checkBadDates(mydate){
var $return=true;
var $returnclass ="available";
$checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', mydate);
for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
   {    
       if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
       {
        $return = false;
        $returnclass= "unavailable";
       }
   }
   return [$return,$returnclass];
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will disable 1st and 3rd saturday

```
beforeShowDay : function (date) {
                    var dayOfWeek = date.getDay ();
                    var dateOfMonth = date.getDate();   
                    var weekOfMonth = (dateOfMonth/7);
                    if ( (dayOfWeek == 6 && (weekOfMonth <= 1 || (weekOfMonth == 3 || (weekOfMonth < 3 && weekOfMonth > 2))))) return [false];
                    else return [true];
                },
```